# Traveling to Afghanistan through Pakistan- transit visa problems

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, pakistan, afghanistan

Basically I have booked my family tickets to Afghanistan through Pakistan. I was well aware that i will be needing a transit on our way back because there is a 20 hour layover in Islamabad and so i applied for a transit like advised. We filled in our application and took them to gerrys in Bradford. Now the visa application has a tick box for what kind of visa you require and one of the boxes say 'Transit'... so you would assume that they issue transit visas. The guy at gerrys dropbox said that they don't issue transit visas and never have and also told us to risk the journey because they probably wont say anything. My question is, has anyone else been in a similar situation? Or has anyone been issed a transit visa before?.

I just think its stupid how you have a tick box for a transit but you don't issue them. Me and my son are British nationals and my husband has an Afghan nationality.

Comment: ISB does not have a sterile transit area; you have to officially enter Pakistan there regardless of the length of your layover. If you're unable to get a visa, you should strongly consider flying through another city. Under no circumstances should you take that horrible advice you received from the guy at Gerry's, unless you want to find out the wide variety of ways your trip can be ruined. Fiurther, it's extremely unusual that Gerry's would reject your application, as the [High Commission website](https://phclondon.org/visa/britishnational/transit/) says to submit it to them.

Comment: I wonder, can you simply apply for the e-visa and skip Gerry's altogether?

Comment: I would contact another of the Gerry’s offices (probably London) to complain about the poor advice given to you by the Bradford office.

Comment: The Pakistan High Commission in London has a [page](https://www.phclondon.org/visa/britishnational/transit/) about transit visas for layovers less than 72 hours. The person you spoke to at Gerry's is wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys soo much. He also advised that i get a visa for ISB in afghanistan before we travel back but we are only there for less than two weeks or i should apply for a visit and get a sponser letter but we dont know anyone in paksitan.

Comment: On the outward leg, your itinerary appears to be home country > Pakistan > Afghanistan, with a 20-hour layover in Pakistan. Looking at the High Commission's webpage cited by Michael Hempton, you'll need a Pakistan transit visa, which might be available to you as an eVisa. But your return itinerary is unclear: what is your layover duration in Pakistan on the way back to your home country?

Comment: Sorry maybe i havnt made it clear it in the question but our 20 hour layover is on our way back home. On our way to Afghanistan we have a 2 hour layover in pakistan.

Comment: Hi, just an update. After seeking so much advice we decided to travel to afghanistan without a transit visa for pakistan. We did this because we were advised by lots of people that you dont need a visa for a 20 hour layover. long story short, we went without a visa and no one questioned us either. When we arived in pakistan they took our passports, we were taken to a hotel where we stayed over night. In the morning they took us back to the airport and gave us our passports back and started our boarding procedure. So no need a visa for a 20hr layover even tho husband has an afghan passport.

Answer (score 1):

This question was self answered by Sudais Amarkhil in a comment:

Hi, just an update. After seeking so much advice we decided to travel to Afghanistan without a transit visa for Pakistan. We did this because we were advised by lots of people that you don't need a visa for a 20 hour layover. long story short, we went without a visa and no one questioned us either. When we arrived in Pakistan they took our passports, we were taken to a hotel where we stayed over night. In the morning they took us back to the airport and gave us our passports back and started our boarding procedure. So no need a visa for a 20 hr layover even though husband has an Afghan passport.

Posted as an answer as it was getting lost as a comment.